Remote Interviews, Face-to-Face Offers
As the title suggests, I had 4 rounds of interview which includes (two technical exams and interview, behavioral interview, culture fit interview) fortunately passed them all. I had a call that the Job Offer would be done on-site. I wonder why this is?
For additional context, I am still employed. The company I am interviewing with is also doing hybrid setup. I have already given them my expected range and hopefully they don't lowball me. Any tips/advice on how to proceed with this? To be honest, even in a face to face setup I am not afraid to walk away but I really want to make this discussion fruitful.

Why do you consider it odd that the company wants to meet face to face with you?  It sounds like you think this won't be worthwhile, but given that the job is hybrid, don't you want to see where you would be working?

Hypothetically (and I have no idea if this applies in your case), it's to deal with the "Person X does the interview, Person Y turns up for the job" issue which does unfortunately happen. By at least seeing you in person before offering you the job, this reduces the chances of this.


Any tips/advice on how to proceed with this?

Go to the on-site meeting ready to talk.
Treat it as another interview round. Be ready to answer their questions. Be prepared with your own questions about anything you need to know in order to accept or reject an offer.
Decide what you require in the offer in order to accept on the spot. Determine ahead of time what salary/bonus/benefit level is enough, and what level would make you reject the offer.

Does this job requires candidates to work remotely, onsite, or hybrid ? Please clarify.

If this is an onsite or hybrid position, then it is reasonable for the company to make the final job offer onsite. Some reasons may be:

They may want to show you the work environment, the computer
labs, yoga room, gym, cafeteria, etc..., which they may think might impress you and make it
easier for you to accept the offer.
They may want the team members to meet you so that they can convince
that this is a nice company to work for. If you like the team
members and feel that you can get along well with them, you may be
more willing to work for the company.
Also, they may want to see whether you TRULY enjoy being onsite or hybrid (as opposed to working remotely).


However, if this is a remote position, then it would be silly for the company to require you to have the final job offer onsite.
